# cuda programming problem

Tags: cuda

I'm very new to cuda .I'm using cuda on my ubuntu 10.04 in device emulation mode. 
I write a code to compute the square of array which is following :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda.h>
__global__ void square_array(float *a, int N)
    {
      int idx = blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
      if (idx<=N) 
       a[idx] = a[idx] * a[idx];
    }
int main(void)
    {
      float *a_h, *a_d; 
      const int N = 10;  
      size_t size = N * sizeof(float);
      a_h = (float *)malloc(size);        
      cudaMalloc((void **) &a_d, size);   
          for (int i=0; i<N; i++) a_h[i] = (float)i;
      cudaMemcpy(a_d, a_h, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
           square_array <<< 1,10>>> (a_d, N);

 cudaMemcpy(a_h, a_d, sizeof(float)*N, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
      // Print results
      for (int i=0; i<N; i++) printf(" %f\n",  a_h[i]);

      free(a_h); 
cudaFree(a_d);
  return 0;
    }
```

When I run this code it show no problem it give me proper output.

Now my problem is that when i use <<<2,5>>> or<<<5,2>>> the result is same .   what is happening on gpu ?
All I understand  is that I just launch cuda kernel with 5 blocks containing 2 thread.
Can anyone explain me how Gpu handle this or implement the launch(kernel call)?

Now my real problem is that when i call the kernel with <<<1,10>>> It is ok . It shows the perfect result. 
but when i call  the kernel with <<<1,5>> the result is following:

```
 0.000000
 1.000000
 4.000000
 9.000000
 16.000000
 5.000000
 6.000000
 7.000000
 8.000000
 9.000000
```

similarly when i reduce or increase the second parameter in kernel call it show different result for example when i change it to <<1,4>> it shows following result:

```
 0.000000
 1.000000
 4.000000
 9.000000
 4.000000
 5.000000
 6.000000
 7.000000
 8.000000
 9.000000
```

Why this result is coming ?
Can any body explain the working of kernel launch call ?

what is blockdim type variable contain ?
Please help me to understand the concept of kernel call launching and working ?
I searched the programming guide but they didn't explain it very well.

Comment: You are changing the value of N (10, 4, 5). Then it is obvious that only the first N elements should be updated. What do you think is What is so confusing about this ?!

Answer (score 5):

The calculation of `idx` in your kernel code is incorrect. If you change it to:

```
int idx = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
```

You might find the results a little easier to understand.

EDIT: For any given kernel launch

```
square_array<<<gridDim,blockDim>>>(...)
```

in the GPU, the automatic variable blockDim will contain the x,y, and z components of the blockDim argument passed in the host side kernel launch. Similarly gridDim will contain the x and y components of the gridDim argument passed in the launch.

Comment: the original code was like that, but it did not change the scenario, or check my question carefully in the last I asked about blockdim, can u explain the working of kernel call please

Comment: I tried my best - as it was originally posted your question was an unformatted, unintelligible pile of rubbish. Have a look at the edit to my posted.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from what talonmies has said, you may need to do the following to have better performance in real world applications.

```
if (idx < N) {
tmp = a[idx];
a[idx] = tmp * tmp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way kernels are invoked in CUDA is like so:

```
kernel<<<numBlocks,numThreads>>>(Kernel arguments);
```

This means that there will be numBlocks blocks with numThreads threads running in each block. For example, if you call

```
 kernel<<<1,5>>>(Kernel args);
```

then 1 block will run with 5 threads running in parallel. and if you call

```
 kernel<<<2,5>>>(Kernel args);
```

then there well be 2 blocks with 5 threads running in each. Unless you alter your device code, the maximum dimension of the array that you are "squaring" is the product numBlocks*numThreads. This explains why not all of the values in your original array were squared.

I suggest you read through the CUDA_C_Programming_Guide.pdf that comes with the CUDA toolkit.